# Disable zoom on a div, but allow zoom on the page (an alternate div)

Tags: css, html, zooming, fixed

Is there a way to disable zoom on a div, or any particular elements on a website? For example, if I wanted the page to be zoomable, but not the #Header div, is there a way to make one zoomable, and the other not zoomable?

Basically, when you zoom on a mobile device, it zooms the Header too, but I want the header to be a fixed size at all times (not zoomable).

I know that you can use this code to disable zooming overall:

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

Comment: If you zoom on the entire page or particular on your header? Or further if you touch just the header or the total page? And, btw: Why you want that? The visitor can't see the full page... a bit crappy, eh?

Comment: Encountered the same problem and was able to (mostly) solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983673/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-fixed-top-navigation-from-zooming-on-mobile/27991099#27991099

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that without clever hacks.

However, you can (and should) use the following CSS to fix zoom issues on mobile devices:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    ...
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    header {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

This code enables `position: absolute` when display width is less or equal 720px, and header becomes the part of the page, rather than being fixed on top.

Comment: It is theoretically possible, check this guy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233076/prevent-that-a-fixed-element-resizes-when-zooming-on-touchscreen

Comment: Is it a similar question with same solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674936/how-to-prevent-zoom-in-inside-a-popups-on-jquery-mobile   >> Not worked for me

Comment: Detect touch and hybrid touch/mouse devices with [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml) and then change the header or fixed element's style value to `absolute`. Like this when zooming on mobile or touch input devices the fixed element(s) do not break the rest of the site but are natively zoomable per browser and OS and most of all user specifications (zoom-level, etc.).

Comment: I would even go as far as saying, **generally** on user zoom set fixed to absolute for Desktop as well as Mobile and Hybrid Touch/Mouse devices. Future proof, let browser and OS handle the Zoom, user happy, accessibility granted, done. Remember, it is not your responsibility for the site to look responsive when it is zoomed! That is the user's decision and in doing so the user wants to zoom in on **every** part of the page, not just the content. So excluding certain divs from zooming is not good.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work @AleksejKomarov. Could you provide a runnable example? (not in a SO snippet, because SO snippets are *not runnable* on Android phones - I already posted a meta-SO request about that)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for Chrome / Android 5: https://imgur.com/a/Yumvk

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that directly. One possible option would be to detect the zooming through js events and scale elements accordingly.

Another option would be to "break" the CTRL key to disable zooming on your website, but that's just a big no-no.

Answer (score 1):

In shorter, you certainly can do that.

You can trap window resize events and resize your floating div according to the dpi change calculated from the various new window and inner width and height attributes.

So, when you *zoom in*, you want to *shrink* the floating div so it retains the original dpi, and vice versa.

This would be an epic fiddle - revisit this answer soon, since I may have to do such a thing. Already noticing some cross-browser inconsistencies with dpi, so yeah, fun.

Comment: Would you have a runnable example @DominicCerisano? Would be super useful, as the the accepted answer doesn't really work (see https://imgur.com/a/Yumvk).

Comment: As I mentioned, this would be a lot of work since it would  require separate implementations for each browser (Chrome, MOZ, etc) and platform (PC, mobile, etc).

Comment: kindof breaks the intend of zooming. if i (the user) want to zoom something, it is my decision to do so, you (the dev) preventing me from that kind of makes me want to leave the page asap

Comment: It implements the intended zooming as described by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem an ended up disabling panning/zooming

```xml
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

and selectively reenable it with this great lib

https://soulfresh.github.io/pan-z/?path=/docs/pan-z--pan-z

Works great without much configuration.

My html-structure is as follows

```xml
<body>
  <header>Sticky unzoomed header</header>
  <main id='main'>Zoomable content</main>
</body>
```

Then I enabled panzooming on the main element

```js
const PanZ = require('@thesoulfresh/pan-z')
new PanZ().init(document.getElementById('main'))
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are using angular there is a way to give one id to your header div and then write the following code in controller:

`document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute('content','user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1');`

I used in my project and it worked well..