# How to create an div background that is not affected by page zoom with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is going to be pretty concise. I saw this Deezer page and I tried to zoom in and out to see that the image is "out of zoom" (see the image below)

[image]

Below is a structure we consider to be my page:

```
<body>
  <div class="visual-header">
    <div class="container">
       SOME TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
  PAGE CONTENT
</body>
```

How am I supposed to use `image.png` of a size of 2000x800 pixels to get this effect?

Comment: Do you mean this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233076/prevent-that-a-fixed-element-resizes-when-zooming-on-touchscreen

Comment: I picked that extension randomly. 
@user3522940, I am not quite sure that is what I need, because the element resizes, its background doesn't

Comment: should just have to define the size, right? where is your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make the background image fit the width of the screen, whatever the zoom level.

```css
BODY
{
    background-image: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

If you want the image to stretch both horizontally and vertically (and not retain its aspect ratio), use:

```css
BODY
{
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Run the code snippet in full page mode to see the effect.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't think of this! Thank you! Such a simple solution

Comment: I edited the answer in case you want the image to stretch in both directions.

Comment: what is the "100vh" there?

Comment: 100vh = 100% of the viewport height; otherwise the BODY heigth is determined by the contents of the page, which may not fill the whole window.