# Is there a way to ignore the existing page zoom and display the modal at zero percent zoom?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have written a simple webpage with bootstrap that shows a varying number of columns and rows of rectangles each with a seperate onclick feedback via modal dialog. 
All is good if the user does not use 'Zoom' to have a closer look at a smaller rectangle. 
Modal is displayed at the same scale which can be too big to read or even find the 'Comment' button.

Is there a way to ignore the existing page zoom and display the modal at zero percent zoom? 
Thank you and sorry if I missed the already answered question.

Comment: [Check this answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233076/prevent-that-a-fixed-element-resizes-when-zooming-on-touchscreen)

Comment: Thank you  @Janatbek one of the answers looks like it could work. I will try it when I can.