# Zooming out / In only visible area of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement the Zooming out/in(browser) only on visible area of website exactly like site http://halfcreative.themes.bitfade.com/. When you zoom out or in, only visible area zooms in or out. I googled for it but didn't find the answer. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific ? With "zoom", do you mean zooming with your browser ?

Comment: @Andri Yes, zooming the browser.

Comment: your question should not be dependent on external resources. This question will make no sense if they redesign (not that it makes sense now).

Comment: You mean that: when you open the page and zoom in and out: the visible content stays the same and you can't see more than before (it's just smaller) ? ^^

Comment: Here is a similar question that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div

Comment: @Andri Yeha, exactly like that

Comment: Use firebug/web console to figure it out yourself - or at least make a start. Hint: it's CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this effect? Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/bJnCV/

## HTML

```
<div id="home">
    <h1>Site Name</h1>
    <p>This is slogan</p>
</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').css({'width':$(window).width(),'height':$(window).height()});    
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#home').css({'width':$(window).width(),'height':$(window).height()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CSS of the site. `(min-)height: 100%;` is a keyword.

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```