# how to make sticky footer that is zoomable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this code and the footer is looking good, but when i zoom-in the page the footer starts rapidly increasing height and it is covering the whole page. I would like the footer same height if i zoom in the page.  :( Thanks for your help

```
    <style>
        footer
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75px;
        background:#808284;    
        bottom:0;


    }
    </style>


        <footer>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible in pure CSS/HTML

[Disable zoom on a div, but allow zoom on the page (an alternate div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div)

If the technique in that link doesn't work, I'm sure you could set a listener for the window resize javascript event and proportionally keep your fixed height from there.