# CSS How to scale site without nav scaling

Tags: html, css, navigation, viewport

I just added scalability to my website, but when I scale, the navigation scales too. **on all devices, (specifically mobile), when the page is zoomed in, the nav zooms as well. How do I keep the nav the same size regardless of the viewport zoom?**

I tried referring to this question, but can't make out the explanation for it. If this is what I'm looking for, can someone please help explain it a little more?

I created this JSFiddle, but being that it's mobile, I'm not sure if it'll be helpful.

Nav:

```
<nav>
<div>
<a href="/">
    <div id="logo"><img src="http://www.lehigh.edu/google/google_search.png" alt="Home"/></div>
    <div id="headtag"><img src="http://codeboxr.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/6_logo_predesign.jpg" alt="Home"/></div>
    <div id="tagline"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-2-4845213826678784.3-hp.gif" alt="Home"/></div>
</a>
</div>
<div> 
<a href="/" class="here">Home</a>
<a href="/about.php">About</a>      
<a href="/services.php">Services</a>
<a href="/pricing.php">Pricing</a>
<a href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
<!--input id="srchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search"-->
</div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foeLo3xx/
1) not zoomed
[image]

2) Zoomed in on mobile (IPhone 5s)
[image]

Comment: Still not getting what you asking for?

Comment: on all devices, (specifically mobile), when the page is zoomed in, the nav zooms as well. How do I keep the nav the same size regardless of the viewport zoom?

Comment: I would suggest you to use percentages(%) for height and width properties.

Comment: the width is set to 100%, i assumed that would keep it at that percentage and shrink all the elements within, but it doesn't work that way

Comment: Have you added the meta information in the head of your project?

Comment: @MarioKurzweil my meta tag is     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=yes" />

Comment: Can you post a picture of your problem? I think this will help.

Comment: @MarioKurzweil just added the photos. second picture shows the issue, the nav zooms as well, instead of staying normally scaled. I want the nav to stay the same as if it's zoomed out, even though the user zooms in the page. So all of nav can be accessed.

Comment: I found this article on stackoverflow it sounds similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no good/reliable way of achieving what you want.

One crude way would be to detect the change in zoom level of and then dynamically resize you navbar container to the current screen width. However, achieving this is not trivial. Another answer on how to detect screen size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers/5078596#5078596) explains the difficulty.

Comment: ok, how do I go about the code for that? I'm assuming javascript is needed , I'm new with that and not familiar with it