# Prevent background image from zooming in

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image. When the user zooms-in the page from the browser (using Ctrl & + or Ctrl + scroll), I don't want to zoom in the image. The image should remain unchanged by the zoom. Is there any way to do this?

This is the styles of the div containing the background image:

```
.owl-slide{
    background-image: url('...');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I know that the normal behaviour would be to zoom-in everything inside the page, even the image. But this is a client's request which needs to be solved, even if I don't agree with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable zoom on a div, but allow zoom on the page (an alternate div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233076/prevent-that-a-fixed-element-resizes-when-zooming-on-touchscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `top` and `left` value for the element and add a `position:absolute`. also set the `width` and `height`.

```css
.owl-slide {
  background-image: url('http://www.freepngimg.com/download/nature/1-2-nature-png-picture.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-slide">Sample div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I zoom-in this page, the image from your example zooms in as well. i would like to prevent that. I also tried to change my code, and the image still zooms in.

Comment: run the snippet and click on full screen. Then try zoom

Comment: A workaround for some might be to use screen units like `vw` and `vh` for `background-size`. In Chrome at least, zoom doesn't seem to affect these. But I'm not sure the spec is clear enough regarding zoom and screen units such that all browsers will definitely behave the same way. Also with this solution, you couldn't get a specific size like "20px".

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can disable the viewport zoom

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I need to keep the page zoomable - I only need to prevent the image from zooming. Your code keeps the entire page from zooming in.