# ignore a div while zooming in chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to zoom in my react app(coreUI) with 'ctrl+PLUS' in chrome. but I want to ignore the height of the header and footer while zooming, is that even possible?

```
//html
<div className="ignore-zoom">
    <h1>title</h1>
<div>

//css
.ignore-zoom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: You can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/ you can try to use "em" base media query to try to solve this.